# SQL Server LEAD more than one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lead

I know that I can use `LAG` and `LEAD` to get the previous and subsequent rows from a results set. What I want to know is how to get the subsequent row, and the row after that one, and the next row. I don't want to use a cursor if pivot, if possible.

Is it possible to `LEAD(n)` with n being the number of rows ahead?

Comment: Documentation is your friend: [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Specifically, look at the Arguments section. Learning to read documentation is a very important skill, and i really suggest taking the time to use it if you have any questions about how a function works, or what it can do.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible:

```
SELECT LEAD(col_name, offset, default_value) OVER(...)
FROM tab
```

For example: `LEAD(col,1)` is default behavior, `LEAD(col, 2)` - second row ahead

Comment: Sincere thank for this, it's exactly what I was looking for.